# iOS 10 remember to "not trust this computer"

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, security, charge

I have a 2015 MBP for work, which I connect my iPhone (6 plus, iOS 10) to charge, and I don't want to trust the computer, **ever**. However, I must click "Don't Trust" every single time I connect for charging. This is asymmetric to the "Trust" selection, which remembers my decision.

Does anyone know if it's possible to stop the 'Trust/Don't Trust' modal from appearing every time, and have the machine not be trusted?

If possible, can you please tell me how?
If not possible, can you please provide proof or evidence that lead you to this conclusion?

Finally, I am not concerned with arguments or opinions about this feature. Only what is outline above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, iOS 10 cannot remember untrusted computers.

From [Apple support document HT202778](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202778):

> If you choose not to trust a computer, you block its access to content on your device. **You'll see the trust alert every time that you connect your iOS device to that computer.**

There is a way to avoid the dialog every time you connect — blocking the data connection while still allowing the USB power connection. You can do that with either (1) a so-called "USB condom" ([SyncStop](http://syncstop.com/), [Juice-Jack Defender](http://www.chargedefense.com/product/juice-jack-defender-turbo/), [PortaPow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QRRZ2QM)) or (2) a ["charge-only" Lightning cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NCR590O).

Comment: How unfortunate, and how incredibly annoying!

Comment: The charge only cable is unavailable. Probably discontinued. But it looks like there is a "PortaPow USB-C to C Data Blocker " still in stock at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 4):

I know your question was for macOS, but a few of the other Windows related questions for doing this got erroneously marked as duplicates of this question.

**Here are the steps for Windows 10:**

**Step #1.** Connect your iPhone/iPad → Head over to the Control Panel.

**Step #2.** Click on Hardware & Sounds → Click and open Device Manager.

**Step #3.** In the Device Manager window, you should see a listing that has the name of your iDevice.

**Step #4.** Right click on iDevice’s name under "Portable Devices" and click on Properties.

**Step #5.** Click on the Hardware tab and then click on Properties → Go to the Driver tab → Click on Disable.

Source: **Option #3** on this page https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-stop-trust-this-computer-message-in-ios-7-on-iphone-ipad/